# "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/var/task/grpc/_cython/__init__.py)"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on aws lambda function, i install the package but i got error

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/var/task/grpc/_cython/**init**.py)

How to solve this type of error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take[the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your source code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to import it in code without haveing it installed on the lambda container? If you gonna use none std libs you should have you function and its libs installed locally and when zip it and upload it to Lambda.

Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggest sir, But I am already Upload the zip format attached to packages but i got same issue

Comment: Does the import works when you try the lib locally?

Comment: yes sir i am first create one environment locally and then need packages install it then convert to zip format and upload it

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to an answer marked correct I wanted to mention that for libraries using C-extensions is important that the layer was built on the same type of system as it runs in lambda. For example, if you're trying to build the layer including grpc on MacOS most likely it won't work since lambda is running on Linux. To make the layer working you have to build it in a Linux system (for example, on the virtual machine or in Docker)